# OpenCV traincascade parameters

Tags: opencv, cascade

I try to train an LBP cascade classifier for emotion recognition i've managed to get 650 faces positives and 1002 negatives. These are my parameters:

```
numPos: 650
numNeg: 1002
numStages: 20
precalcValBufSize[Mb] : 1500
precalcIdxBufSize[Mb] : 1500
stageType: BOOST
featureType: LBP
sampleWidth: 24
sampleHeight: 24
boostType: GAB
minHitRate: 0.995
maxFalseAlarmRate: 0.5
weightTrimRate: 0.95
maxDepth: 2
maxWeakCount: 100
```

The positives consists of 650 frontal faces laughing and the negatives consists of some faces not laughing and most of the others are random pics of animals, nature, trucks etc

I don't get it why it doesn't find anything most of the parameters have default values.
Any suggestion is really appreciated.

---

I have increased the number of positive faces to 735 and negative to 1700. The xml is loaded correctly but it detects random parts from the background or my face and laughing doesn't change the result.

Comment: If IT doesn't find *anything* then it could be that the cascade.xml file is not being loaded.

Comment: Have you succeeded with this? Any progress?